# cannot insert data into table in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

here, i try to insert some data from my form, but there is always not inserted and i dont know where is the error, hope anyone tell me :)

my insert code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name (buyername, buyerjob, buyercompany, buyeraddress, buyercity, buyerpost, buyerphone, buyerfax, buyeremail, buyerweb, buyernob, buyertoo, buyerhonor)
`VALUES ('$name', '$job', '$company', '$address', '$city', '$post', '$phone', '$fax', '$email', '$web', '$nob', '$too', '$bhonor')";
```

is there any error? hope anyone help

**Error Message**

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(reg_db.buyer_db, CONSTRAINT buyer_db_ibfk_1 FOREIGN KEY (spouse_id) REFERENCES 
spouse_db (spouse_id))
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: there is no error message,

Comment: Do you check for one? Have you run this from the mysql command line?

Comment: i try using 

$result=mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "Back to main page";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}

but there is just show ERROR and dont know what error is

Comment: So you don't check for one. Use `mysql_error()` to see what your error is. That will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: You are missing the 'VALUES' at INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES(...)

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`reg_db`.`buyer_db`, CONSTRAINT `buyer_db_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`spouse_id`) REFERENCES `spouse_db` (`spouse_id`)) 

this is what mysql said

Comment: It means the spouseId matching this buyer does not exist anymore, you better truncate your table and start back fresh

Answer (score 0):

You don't set a value of spouse_id field,
but error message says that it is mandatory and must be set to a value present in spouse_db table.